# C++ forward declaration of ‘class GenericModel / missing class name / inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, header-files

I have stumbled upon an inheritance problem. So I have 3 classes in 3 separate headers defined like this:

GenericObject -> Object
GenericObject -> LightObject

First the inherited object:

```
#ifndef GENERICMODEL_HPP
#define GENERICMODEL_HPP

#define NO_SDL_GLEXT
#define GLM_FORCE_RADIANS 
#include <GL/glew.h>//before opengl
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>

#include "GenericShader.hpp"
#include "BaseObject.hpp" 
#include "Scene.hpp"

#define FRAGMENT_SHADER 0
#define VERTEX_SHADER 1

class GenericShader;
class Scene;

class GenericModel: public BaseObject{
public:
    GenericModel();
    ~GenericModel();
    virtual void Render();
    bool LoadShaderProgram(char*,char*);
    void BindShaders(GenericShader *);
    void UpdatePosition(glm::vec3);
    void UpdateRotation(float,glm::vec3);
    void UpdateScale(glm::vec3);
    void UpdateMatrix();

    bool shadersLoaded;
    int scenePosNum = 0;
    GLuint programID;//for now
    GLuint vertexBuffer;
    glm::mat4 MVP;
    glm::mat4 modelMatrix;
    //Scene *scene;

protected:

    GenericShader *shaderObj= NULL;
    GLuint vaoID;
    Uint32 verticesCount;
    float angle; 
    glm::vec3 locationVector;
    glm::vec3 rotationVector;
    glm::vec3 scaleVector;
    Scene *scene;
};
#endif
```

Second:

```
#ifndef MODEL_HPP
#define MODEL_HPP


#include "GenericModel.hpp"
#include <libxml/parser.h>
#include <libxml/tree.h>

class GenericModel;

class Model : public GenericModel{

public:
    Model();
    ~Model();
    void Render();
    bool LoadModelOBJ(char *);
    bool LoadModelXML(char *);
    bool LoadTexture(char *);

private: 
    GLuint textureID;
    GLuint texture;
    bool modelLoaded;
    bool textureLoaded;
    GLuint textureBuffer;
    bool OpenOBJModel(char*, std::vector<glm::vec3> & , std::vector<glm::vec2> & , std::vector<glm::vec3> & );
    bool OpenXMLModel(char *filename, std::vector<glm::vec3> & vertOut, std::vector<glm::vec2> & uvOut, std::vector<glm::vec3> & normalOut);
};
#endif
```

Third:

```
#ifndef LIGHT_OBJECT_HPP
#define LIGHT_OBJECT_HPP

#include "GenericModel.hpp"

class GenericModel; //PROBLEM

class LightObject: public GenericModel {

public:
    LightObject();
    ~LightObject();
    void Render();
    glm::vec3 GetLight();
    void SetLight(glm::vec3);

private:
    glm::vec3 lightIntenzity;

};
#endif
```

When i try to compile them, i get error

> LightObject.hpp:9:27: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class GenericModel’
>    class LightObject: public GenericModel {
>                              ^
>   LightObject.hpp:7:7: error: forward declaration of ‘class GenericModel’
>    class GenericModel;

If I delete the forward declaration, new error appears:

> LightObject.hpp:9:40: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token
>    class LightObject: public GenericModel {

This gets me pretty confused since it does not have a problem with the Model class, which is done in same way. Forward declaration with include. Could anyone point me in right direction? Thanks in advance! (BTW Base object is just ID)

Comment: If `GenericModel` doesn't need the full definition of `GenericShader` and `Scene` in its header file, why do you forward declare them and include their header? You probably have a circular dependency somewhere, and removing unnecessary includes will help to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably one of these includes is including LightObject.hpp:

```
#include "GenericShader.hpp"
#include "BaseObject.hpp" 
#include "Scene.hpp"
```